# Saving contents of listview as a CSV File in c#

Tags: c#

I have a standalone c# App with a listview that display data read by my program.
I am saving it as an excel file it works great , but the data when saved is dumped all in column, I have tried saving it as csv file ,but I cant get it to do what I want let each distinct be on a separate column please any heads up would highly welcome
This is how my output is designed and I want that each should be on a separate column when I open the excel file.

```
   listView1.Items.Add(vis.brand+ "," + (vis.Count) + ","vis.model + "," + Math.Round(vis.sum));
```

Comment: `","vis.model` should be `"," + vis.model`.  What exactly is not working?  Note that if you have quotes in text, you have to escape it with double quote (Ed "The Hacker" Jones => Ed ""The Hacker"" Jones), and if you have commas or newlines in a string you have to quote that cell (Ed, Jr => "Ed, Jr").

Comment: Ok thank you Eric I will give a shot right away,I am trying to save the file as csv so it can recognize comma, and thus have my data by in columns rather than just dumping everything in one column.

Comment: The accepted answer is mostly correct, but see also my answer for code that handles important edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/export-ListView-to-CSV-39cd5f72) example, choose the C# version.

It should do exactly what you want to achieve. This function should do the trick:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //declare new SaveFileDialog + set it's initial properties
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog {
                Title = "Choose file to save to",
                FileName = "example.csv",
                Filter = "CSV (*.csv)|*.csv",
                FilterIndex = 0,
                InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
            };

            //show the dialog + display the results in a msgbox unless cancelled

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {

                string[] headers = ListView1.Columns
                           .OfType<ColumnHeader>()
                           .Select(header => header.Text.Trim())
                           .ToArray();

                string[][] items = ListView1.Items
                            .OfType<ListViewItem>()
                            .Select(lvi => lvi.SubItems
                                .OfType<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
                                .Select(si => si.Text).ToArray()).ToArray();

                string table = string.Join(",", headers) + Environment.NewLine;
                foreach (string[] a in items)
                {
                    //a = a_loopVariable;
                    table += string.Join(",", a) + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                table = table.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(sfd.FileName, table);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks McRonald, so your code is c# I guess, I dont understand when you say use the c# version :)

Comment: Thank you very much Sir/Dr/my Guru McRonald you saved me ,been working on this since two days ,I really appreciate your timely support,God bless ya:))

Comment: I was referencing to the link i gave ya. Because on the microsoft site it allows you to download a VB.NET and a C# version. And god bless you to :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @McRonald mostly covers it, but will fail for important edge cases.

If you have a comma or quote in any string, it will mess up the output.  For example if you had a CSV with columns LastName and FirstName, someone with a suffix like ", Jr" would throw off the commas:

```
LastName, FirstName
Smith, John
Baker, Jr, Fred
```

I developed an extension method that applies any necessary escaping to a string that is being written to a cell of a CSV file (the code could be shortened, but is easiest to follow as written):

```
static public class CsvExtensions
{
    static public string CsvQuote(this string text)
    {
        if (text == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        bool containsQuote = false;
        bool containsComma = false;
        bool containsNewline = false;
        bool containsCR = false;
        int len = text.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < len && (containsComma == false || containsQuote == false); i++)
        {
            char ch = text[i];
            if (ch == '"')
            {
                containsQuote = true;
            }
            else if (ch == ',')
            {
                containsComma = true;
            }
            else if (ch == '\r')
            {
                containsCR = true;
            }
            else if (ch == '\n')
            {
                containsNewline = true;
            }
        }

        bool mustQuote = containsComma || containsQuote || containsCR || containsNewline;

        if (containsQuote)
        {
            text = text.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
        }

        if (mustQuote)
        {
            return "\"" + text + "\"";  // Quote the cell and replace embedded quotes with double-quote
        }
        else
        {
            return text;
        }
    }

}
```

You would place all of that code in it's own class, then use it like this (taking a line of code from @McRonald's answer):

```
table += string.Join(",", a) + Environment.NewLine;
```

becomes

```
table += string.Join(",", a.CsvQuote()) + Environment.NewLine;
```